# Webpack require really slow, debugging JS profile

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server

From Chrome devtools Timeline profiling my Angular2 app load time is really huge, for **single bundled file** it takes up to `2.66 seconds`, call stack snapshot look like this (zoomed for nice readability)

[image]

Several calls to **webpack_require** takes about `1.27 seconds`, `855.05 milliseconds` and so on, which drastically affect app load time. Are there any known webpack problems related to this? I only found https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2219, issue that is still open without general solution.